# jQuery Load function not loading inside a div but loads new page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have following html markup:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="search"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</button>
<div class="row text-center" style="margin-top: 50px;">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="content-area"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to load a page.php inside #content-area. This is the jQuery I used for this:

```
$("#search").click(function(){
    $("#content-area").load("page.php");
});
```

The problem is page.php is not loading inside #content-area but it loads as a new page itself. I want page.php to load inside #content-area. Please help.

Comment: get the load into a variable and use html() method for variable data assignment to div.

Comment: Are you doing any type of search ? use ajax for that.

Comment: are you giving perfect path of page.php ? please check it once.

Comment: @DeepKakkar     I used this code `$("#search").click(function(){
  var loadData = load("populateCustomer.php");
  $("#content-area").html(loadData);
 });` Still it is loading on a new page and not inside my div

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load

Comment: @LearningMode   Yes. The search button sends a variable to page.php which queries a database and populates a table using while loop. I want to display that table inside #content-area.

Comment: @IndraGotamey This should actually done by ajax, You can see SRK's Answer. How it should be.

Comment: @LearningMode   I dont want to use ajax. My table is already populated in page.php. I just want that table to load in #content area.

Comment: @IndraGotamey Perhaps you do not understand - `.load()` ***is*** ajax -- it is a shortcut for the method suggested by SRK. SRK merely used the long form, but the short forms of that the same method SRK describes are: `$.get()`, `$.post()` and `$.load()` - see http://api.jquery.com/load/ *(notice the "Category" breadcrumbs up top)*

Answer (score 1):

//you have to make ajax call to get content without page load.

```
$("#search").click(function(){
          $.ajax({
                url: 'page.php', // point to server-side PHP script
                dataType: 'json', // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                type: 'POST',           
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status === 'success')
                {
                   $("#content-area").html(data);

                }
                else if (data.status === 'error')
                {
                    alert(data.message);
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                return false;
                Msg.show('Something went wrong, Please try again!','danger', 7000);
            }
        });    
});
```

Comment: Yes use the ajax is better ... ki ki ki ki kiran :) @SRK

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below code its working fine for me.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-success" id="search"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</button>
<div class="row text-center" style="margin-top: 50px;">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="content-area"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
    $("#search").click(function(){
    $("#content-area").load("test1.php");
});
</script>
```